# I have someone that just Doxxed me online, by obtaining information from their own community using paypal donate service.

Tags: internet

I have someone that just Doxxed me online, by obtaining information from their own community using PayPal donate service.

He used personal information to harass me in the real world, by calling personal house phone and giving the number out publicly to friends in his community. Can he use information that he obtained from PayPal to harass someone outside his gaming community by giving out a personal name and phone number?

Answer (score 2):

This will depend somewhat on your jurisdiction. Your name and phone number are not information which "the reasonable man" would find publicizing to be offensive, so this would not qualify as the tort of public disclosure of private facts. If a person actually harasses you by phone, that is against the law, but it is not against the law to publicly reveal a person's name or number, and in general the First Amendment guarantees everybody the right to say anything, other than threats. Your description does not make it clear how they learned your name and phone number: there is the possibility that they violated some part of their terms of service. However, you would not have direct legal recourse against the person who revealed this information, only PayPal would.

Comment: um i seen a screenshot of my own personal paypal information.